# Smtp server - "Failure Sending Mail" on powershell ping script

Tags: .net, powershell, iis-7, smtp

I am working on a Powershell script that pings the server and sends me an email if the ping fails. Everything works except for the email part. The error I get when I use the code below (after pinging and getting back the response) is "Failure sending mail." Hm. I've tried changing my authentication, but that didn't change anything. Currently, it is configured in IIS to run on localhost, port 25. Any ideas on what I need to change? Firewalls? Different port?

```
$smtpServer = "localhost:25"

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = "address@mail.com"

$msg.To.Add("destination@mail.com")

$msg.Subject = "Warning: ping failed on $server"

$msg.Body = "The server $server with ip address $ip does not reply!"

$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with IIS.  Have you configured relaying?

Comment: I went into MMC to do so--I cannot find SMTP Site Property as it should be. Do I need to install it first? I also went in to SMTP email in IIS manager and made sure it was running .NET 4.0.

Comment: I would recommend using a guide to configure SMTP in IIS.  If you have additional trouble setting it up, you may want to post a topic on ServerFault (another member of the stackexchange group)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the port from the $smtpServer variable ($smtpServer = "localhost"). 
The port (25 for default) is already configured on $smtp ($smtp.Port)

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using ?
If you are using Exchange 2007/2010, you need additional configuration on Exchange side, as per this article.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/12/28/3397620.aspx